# Integrating a function from negative inf to positive inf with assumptions of variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

The function is $e^{a x^{2}}$ and to be integrated over the domain from negative infinity to positive infinity.
The variable `a` is to be positive using the `Assumption` function.

Here are my codes:

```
Limit[
  Integrate[E^(-a \[ScriptCapitalX]^2), {\[ScriptX], -ℓ, ℓ}, Assumptions -> a > 0],
  ℓ -> Infinity]
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can directly evaluate `Integrate[E^(-a x^2), {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> a > 0]`.

Comment: Are ou integrating $e^{ax^2}$ or $e^{-ax^2}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To correct the mistakes in the OP's code:

First, you have a function of `\[ScriptCapitalX]` which you are integrating over `\[ScriptX]` - no wonder it doesn't give the result you expected, because the input is not the one you're talking about. So - second - ["get rid of formatting"](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2131/22013). Thence, try

```
Limit[Integrate[E^(-a x^2), {x, -l, l}, Assumptions -> a > 0], l -> Infinity]
```

> Limit[ConditionalExpression[(Sqrt[π] Erf[Sqrt[a] l])/Sqrt[a], 
>     l ∈ Reals], l -> ∞]

That's better, but why not perfect? Because you put `Assumptions` in the `Integrate` only, and the `Limit` doesn't know now what is `a`. So, try again with

```
Limit[Integrate[E^(-a x^2), {x, -l, l}, Assumptions -> a > 0], 
 l -> Infinity, Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

> Sqrt[π]/Sqrt[a]

which is now correct. But why one should type `Assumptions` twice? In this case it's simpler to wrap the whole expression in `Assuming`:

```
Assuming[a > 0, 
 Limit[Integrate[E^(-a x^2), {x, -l, l}], l -> Infinity]
]
```

> Sqrt[π]/Sqrt[a]

---

Or just go directly with the infinite limits in the integral:

```
Integrate[E^(-a x^2), {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> a > 0]
```

> Sqrt[π]/Sqrt[a]

Comment: Elegantly put. Thank you!